# How to change feature color?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#, polygon

I have feature (`polygon`) was gotten by `spatial query` from the map.

How to change its color?

I used this code but it didn't work

```
IMxDocument mxDocument = application.Document as IMxDocument;
IActiveView activeView = mxDocument.ActiveView;
IRgbColor rgbColor = new RgbColorClass();
ISimpleFillSymbol fillSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbolClass();
IElement element = new PolygonElementClass();
rgbColor.Red = 255;
rgbColor.Green = 40;
rgbColor.Blue = 50;
fillSymbol.Color = rgbColor;
element.Geometry = parcel.Shape;
IFillShapeElement pFillElement = (IFillShapeElement)element;
pFillElement.Symbol = fillSymbol;
activeView.Refresh();
```

Comment: your code does not use the `objectid`, and also does not add the pFillElement to any layer.

Comment: @til_b i get the feature by object id. in line 10 i already got the parcel.shap. and about pFillElement i'll search about how i can add it to the layer thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using `IGraphicsContainer` [see this link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//004900000067000000)

Answer (score 0):

My workflow for "re-coloring" features is as follows:

First i setup the layer to be symbolized by categories, and set the correct options, classes, etc. with the normal ArcGIS workflow.

Then I use scripting to set the value of the field the data is colored with to my wanted value.

I use this for a national grid where i want to highlight certain grid cells.
The feature class/shapefile is symbolized on the field "selected", displayed as grey when selected=0 and as yellow when selected=1. Then its simply (in python):

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(<shapefile to update>, ("ID","selected")) as cursor:
  for data_row in cursor:
    if data_row[0] <should be set to selected>:
      data_row[1] = 1
    else:
      data_row[1] = 0
    cursor.updateRow(data_row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your element to a graphics layer.  See this sample from ESRI.

```
Dim pCGLayer As ICompositeGraphicsLayer
Set pCGLayer = New CompositeGraphicsLayer

'Name the new graphics layer
Dim pLayer As ILayer
Set pLayer = pCGLayer
pLayer.Name = "TestPoint"

'Add the layer to the map
pMap.AddLayer pCGLayer

'Get the graphics layer and screen display
Dim pGrLayer As IGraphicsLayer
Set pGrLayer = pCGLayer

Dim pScreenDisplay As IScreenDisplay
Set pScreenDisplay = pMxApp.Display

'Add the marker element ot the layer graphics container
Dim pGraphicCont As IGraphicsContainer
Set pGraphicCont = pGrLayer
pGraphicCont.AddElement pMarkerElement, 0
With pScreenDisplay
  .ActiveCache = 0
  .StartDrawing pScreenDisplay.hDC, 0
  .SetSymbol pSimpleMarkerSymbol
  pElement.Draw pScreenDisplay, Nothing
  .FinishDrawing
End With

'Refresh/redraw the display with the new point
pMxDoc.ActiveView.Refresh
```

http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/21613

Answer (score 0):

ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IColor rgbColor = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.RgbColorClass();
  rgbColor.RGB = 255;

ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IMarkerSymbol markerSymbol = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IMarkerSymbol)simpleMarker3DSymbol; // Explicit cast
  markerSymbol.Color = rgbColor;
  markerSymbol.Size = 100000;

Answer (score -2):

[Visual Basic 6.0]

```
Dim aColor As IRGBColor 
Set aColor = New RGBColor 

aColor.Red = 133 
aColor.Green = 135 
aColor.Blue = 43 
aColor.Transparency = 50
```